# Append count as table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have the following SQL-query:

```
SELECT Device, Value    
FROM tbTest 
WHERE Class LIKE 'OperatingSystem'  
AND Type LIKE 'Caption'     
ORDER BY Device
```

This results in the following table:

```
Device    Value
ITADMIN   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
NB6826    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
TOPDESK   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 
W1DC1     Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
W1DC2     Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
W1SRVSEP  Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 
W2DC1     Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
```

What I would like to achive is counting all occurences of a field in a row and append it to every row as a new column.
So basically I need a query that outputs this:

```
Device    Value                                        Count
ITADMIN   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter     1
NB6826    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro                     1
TOPDESK   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard    3
W1DC1     Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter  2
W1DC2     Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter  2
W1SRVSEP  Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard    3
W2DC1     Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard    3
```

Is there any way to do it? All my tries have resulted in either unprocessable queries or unusable output. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample content in tbTest. Based on the SQL query you gave, I expect to see Device, Value, Class and Type columns. Without sample data, you're leaving it up to the reader to guess and you may get multiple differing answers because of the ambiguity.

Comment: This is actual data from tbTest. Why are you expecting to see four columns in the output? I am only selecting `Device` and `Value`, hence two columns

Comment: Which Dbms are you you using?

Comment: It's running on an MS-SQL Server 11.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a windowed count function which will count the number of records in the value column for each distinct value

```
   SELECT Device,
           Value,
           COUNT(value) OVER (PARTITION BY value)
    FROM tbTest 
    WHERE Class LIKE 'OperatingSystem'  
    AND Type LIKE 'Caption'     
    ORDER BY Device
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Now I think I have to do a bit of reading on `OVER` ans `PARTITION BY`

Comment: They're really powerful once you understand them. I recommend this video https://youtu.be/KwEjkpFltjc